# How to intuitively understand prolongations

Tags: lie-algebras, intuition, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, graded-modules

This question is concerned with the algebraic side of the theory of prolongations as explained in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183525778) by V. Guillemin and S. Sternberg. Let me first introduce my notation.

We're working with a finite dimensional real vector space $T$ with basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and its dual space, $T^*$, with basis $\{x^k\}_{k=1}^n$.

First of all we consider the symmetric algebra $S(T^*)$, which can be identified with the algebra of polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x^1,\dots,x^n]$ and is graded as
$$
S(T^*)=\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}S^k(T^*),
$$
and each $S^k(T^*)$ can be identified with the homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$.

Every derivation $D\in\operatorname{Der}S(T^*)$ is uniquely determined by it's action in $S^1(T^*)$, so there aren't any derivations of degree less than $-1$. Also, there is a natural isomorphism between $T$ and $\operatorname{Der}S(T^*)_{-1}$ given by
$$
\partial_v(\eta) = \eta(v),
$$
for every $v\in T$ and $\eta\in T^*\cong S^1(T^*)$. With this we obtain the natural identification 
$$
\partial_{e_i}\leftrightarrow\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.
$$
With all this it's easily shown that in general,
$$
\operatorname{Der}S(T^*)_k\cong\operatorname{Hom}(T^*,S^{k+1}(T^*))\cong S^{k+1}(T^*)\otimes T,
$$
and we can identify $S(T^*)\otimes T$ with the set of polynomial vector fields of $T$. With this we can equip $\operatorname{Der}S(T^*)$, seen as a subset of $\operatorname{End}S(T^*)$, with a Lie algebra structure that that preserves the graduation.

**Definition**
Given $h\subset\operatorname{Hom}(T^*,S^{k+1}(T^*))$ in the paper I mention they define the (first) prolongation of $h$ as the set
$$
j^{(1)}h:=\{\tau\in\operatorname{Hom}(T^*,h):\tau(u)v=\tau(v)u\,\forall\,u,v\in T^*\}.
$$
Now, consider a family of subspaces $g^k\subseteq S^{k+1}(T^*)\otimes T$ for $k=-1,\dots, i$, for some fixed $i$ and with $g^{-1}=T$. What we're going to do is prolong this family of subspaces to form a Lie algebra.

This obscure definition has eluded me for a some days now and I don't know yet how to understand what's really behind it. I've tried to show that my definition is equivalente to Definition 1.1 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611696.pdf), but I no longer think that's true.

Also, according to [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0747717108001156/1-s2.0-S0747717108001156-main.pdf?_tid=1cad6324-0cf2-11e5-a9d5-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1433667150_fd961adc62436bdd7943ee74e34f06c3)

> A single prolongation of a system of order $q$ consists of augmenting the system with all possible derivatives of its equations [...]

yet I can't make sense of this in my framework.

I tried showing that 
$$
j^{(1)}g^i\cong\{f\in S^{i+2}(T^*)\otimes T: \partial_w f\in g^i\,\forall\, w\in T\},
$$
but now I'm convinced (not a 100%) this is false.

**Edit:** This last statement seems to be also used in [the book Will Jagy recommends in the comments.](http://www.amazon.ca/Exterior-Differential-Systems-R-L-Bryant/dp/3540974113)

**Note:** I'm creating a "prolongation-theory" tag which doesn't exist ATM. If the tag is so irrelevant it should be deleted so be it.

**Bounty Edit:** The jet-bundles tag may be misleading, since I'm interested mostly in the algebraic side of this. I'll leave it as it's a closely related topic.

**(probably) Final edit:** This question is mostly answered in chapter 4 of the book recommended by James S. Cook in the comments: 'Cartan For Beginners' by Ivey and Landsberg.

Comment: might help to see the differential geometry side of this, Chern certainly supported the "differentiate it" sentiment.  http://www.amazon.ca/Exterior-Differential-Systems-R-L-Bryant/dp/3540974113  I have a fairly basic book with specific problems solved, by Alois Svec, cannot find it. Note that Chern often said "It helps to be vague about bundles"

Comment: Alois Svec, Global Differential Geometry of Surfaces. 1981

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the suggestion and references. It appears Svec's book is harder to find, but I can probably get my hands in the one you link. I want to keep everything algebraic, since algebra it's my confort zone (more than geometry), but if it's necessary I'll 'differentiate it'. I know Peter Olver's book treats this topic in some depth, but all from a more geometric point of view.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change the original tags: the problem is essentially algebraic, therefore I have added more relevant tags in this direction (non-commutative algebra, tensor products, graded modules, Lie algebras). I have deleted "prolongation-theory" because, being so new, nobody was following it yet, and "jet-bundles" because it misleads the reader into thinking that it is a question about differential geometry (it happened to me). I apologize if this is contrary to your will, please feel free to roll back to the original version if so. I only wanted to increase visibility.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at Cartan For Beginners by Ivey and Landsberg. My intuition is that the prolongation is differentiation. Since partial derivatives commute we have to account for that by using symmetrized tensors. Also, the use of a vector space and its dual is important as it gives us a coordinate-invariant presentation of a PDE. The so-called Gauss map and Tableau work together to give us an algebraification of the PDE. I'm still working on really understanding all this myself.

Comment: @AlexM. I'm ok with the tags you removed, but since I'm not an expert in these topics I'm not sure about the some of the ones you added. Shouldn't this be tagged under commutative-algebra for example?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thank you for your comment! I just downloaded the book and after a quick read it seems it explains a lot about what I'm asking. I'll update my answer if I find anything meaningful.

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Despite symmetric tensor algebras being commutative, they are still regarded as a topic in tensor algebras which are essentially non-commutative.

Comment: @AlexM. I see, thank you.